# Android share action doesn't do anything

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I'm following a course on Udacity on building an Android app (weather, in this case). I've been having trouble implementing a Share action. After getting some advice from another forum, I changed the min SDK version from 10 or 11 to 17, since this is just a learning activity. Currently, I have the "Share" button showing up in the action bar, but tapping on it does nothing. I tried putting it in the overflow menu, but still, nothing. I tried some debugging, but I don't know where the button click is supposed to be handled; the debugger goes through and creates the shareIntent object, but then nothing seems to happen with it. I looked at [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionEvents), but when I try to handle the sharing in the view's onOptionsItemSelected, I get a null pointer exception on the call to createShareIntent. What am I missing?

Here's the nested fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_fragment, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(getActivity());
    if(mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share action provider is null");
    }
}
```

Here's the containing view's onOptionsItemSelected, with the problematic code commented out:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_share) {
        //DetailFragment details = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detailFragment");
        //startActivity(details.createShareIntent());
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And here's the createShareIntent method:

```
private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had put `android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider` in a layout XML file instead of a menu one. I don't think the Udacity course I'm taking mentioned the correct location for that (perhaps due to compatibility things).

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, I have the "Share" button showing up in the action bar, but tapping on it does nothing.

Make sure you are going through your code branch that calls `setShareIntent()`, and make sure that the device or emulator you are testing on has an activity from some app that supports `ACTION_SEND` for `text/plain`. Also, if there is only one activity that supports `ACTION_SEND` for `text/plain`, the icon for that activity will appear adjacent to the `ShareActionProvider` share icon, and you would tap the activity icon to share with that activity.

> I tried some debugging, but I don't know where the button click is supposed to be handled

That is inside the implementation of `ShareActionProvider`.

> I looked at this doc, but when I try to handle the sharing in the view's onOptionsItemSelected, I get a null pointer exception on the call to createShareIntent.

`onOptionsItemSelected()` is for regular action items, not action providers.

Comment: Yes, when I debug, I get into the `if(mShareActionProvider != null)` block. I'm running the app on my own Nexus 4, which I believe has plenty of share activities.

Your other comments are helpful for clarity.

Comment: @spartanhooah: FWIW, here is a complete sample app that implements the same sort of `ShareActionProvider` that you are trying: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ShareNative

Comment: I looked at that implementation, and tried doing something similar in the onCreateOptionsMenu method, but apparently I can't get a valid ActionProvider object from the MenuItem - I saw the "Share action provider is null" message in the log when I tried that route.

Comment: @spartanhooah: Make sure that you have synchronized your action bar and `ShareActionProvider` implementations. The sample that I linked to uses the native action bar and native `ShareActionProvider`. If you are using `appcompat-v7`, or ActionBarSherlock, there will be other classes you need to use (and, in the case of `appcompat-v7`, different menu XML resource attributes).

Comment: I was using the the `appcompat-v7` library, but switched to native `ShareActionProvider`. What do you mean by synchronizing the implementations?

Comment: @spartanhooah: If you are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar (e.g., `ActionBarActivity`), you need to use the `appcompat-v7` version of `ShareActionProvider`, not the native one.

Comment: I'm not using the compatibility library at all. (Also, sorry about moving this; I mis-tapped on my phone.)